# Regex for splitting a string which contains commas?

Tags: python, string, split

How could I split a string by comma which contains commas itself in Python? Let's say the string is:

```py
object = """{"alert", "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that now, try later", "success", "Welcome, user"}"""
```

How do I make sure I only get four elements after splitting?

Comment: `object = {` and `}` is also included in the string?

Comment: Only the {}. But I can easily strip them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> obj = '{"alert", "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that now, try later", "success", "Welcome, user"}'
>>> literal_eval(obj[1:-1])
('alert', 'Sorry, you are not allowed to do that now, try later', 'success', 'Welcome, user')
```

[On Python3.2+](http://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/90bf0631bfb8/) you can simply use `literal_eval(obj)`.

Comment: @thefourtheye, According to quick test, Python 2.7 throw `ValueError`, while Python 3.3 recoginize it.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'\"(.+?)\"', obj)
['alert', 'Sorry, you are not allowed to do that now, try later',
 'success', 'Welcome, user']
```